# SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest Doesn't Output Results from Speech Recognition Until After Thread Calling It Completes

Tags: swift, macos, speech-recognition

I am trying to use `SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest` to transcribe audio files in a terminal application. While I have it working in a preliminary form, I'm running into an odd issue. It appears to only output the voice recognition results (both partial and complete) after the main thread terminates in my test applications. Note I am a Swift noob, so I might be missing something obvious.

Below I have a complete Xcode Playground application which demonstrates the issue. The output from the playground writes `Playground Execution Complete` and then I begin receiving partial outputs followed by the final output. Note that if I add a `sleep(5)` prior to the `print` it will wait 5 seconds and then output the `print`, and only then after the main thread has concluded begin processing the text. I have seen similar behavior in a GUI test application, where it only begins processing the text after the method call kicking off the request completes.

I have tried repeatedly checking the state of the task that is returned, sleeping between each check with no luck.

I have also tried calling the recognition task inside a DispatchQueue, which appears to run successfully in the background based on CPU usage, but the Partial and Final prints never appear until the application completes, at which point the console fills up with Partials followed by the Final.

Does anyone know of a way to have the speech recognition begin processing without the application thread completing? Ideally I would like to be able to kick it off and sleep for brief periods repeatedly, checking if the recognition task has completed in between each.

Edited below to match version immediately prior to figuring out the solution.

```
import Speech

var complete = false

SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization {
    authStatus in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if authStatus == .authorized {
            print("Good to go!")
        } else {
            print("Transcription permission was declined.")
            exit(1)
        }
    }
}

guard let myRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer() else {
   print("Recognizer not supported for current locale!")
   exit(1)
}

if !myRecognizer.isAvailable {
   // The recognizer is not available right now
   print("Recognizer not available right now")
   exit(1)
}

if !myRecognizer.supportsOnDeviceRecognition {
    print("On device recognition not possible!")
    exit(1)
}

let path_to_wav = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: "/tmp/harvard.wav", isDirectory: false)

let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: path_to_wav)
request.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = true

print("About to create recognition task...")

myRecognizer.recognitionTask(with: request) {
    (result, error) in
  guard let result = result else {
     // Recognition failed, so check error for details and handle it
     print("Recognition failed!!!")
     print(error!)
     exit(1)
  }
    if result.isFinal {
        print("Final: \(result.bestTranscription.formattedString)")
        complete = true
    } else {
        print("Partial: \(result.bestTranscription.formattedString)")
    }
}

print("Playground execution complete.")
```

Comment: As you've gathered, the completion handler runs asynchronously, and will be far slower to complete than your main thread.  You can add tthe `PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true` statement to your playground so it continues to execute which will allow you hanlde delayed async responses.

Comment: and you can call `PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()` when it is finally done, maybe from the completion handler?

Comment: I understand that it is asynchronous, my primary issue is that it no results appear until after the main thread ends. I can sleep for >> longer than it takes to process, and yet all the printed output from the call doesn't appear until after the main thread ends. 

Example: for the harvard.wav I'm using for the above test, it takes ~10 seconds to process. If I add a sleep for 20 seconds, I see the CPU usage spike for the first 10 seconds and then the CPU usage drops, but never get any console output for another 10 seconds until execution stops.

Comment: If you are sleeping on the main thread I'm pretty sure it will block the main thread so it won't be available for any output until the sleep ends.  At which point it will write to the console as expected.  I don't quite understand what behaviour you are hoping for, but If you want to do anything with the output ypu will have to invoke that action from the completion handler (and in a playground set the indefinite execution as above)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! `sleep` doesn't actually let background tasks execute. Instead by adding the following:

```
let runLoop = RunLoop.current
let distantFuture = NSDate.distantFuture as NSDate
while complete == false && runLoop.run(mode: RunLoop.Mode.default, before: distantFuture as Date) {}
```

to the end just before the last print works (results begin appearing immediately, and the final print prints right after the final results).